# Resetting the AUTO_INCREMENT value of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I need to reset the auto_increment value of a column in the database, I know that I can use: `ALTER TABLE 'table' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` but it is not working. I am using MySQL 5.6.14.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Be more specific

Comment: It is like I didn't do anything, it keeps the old maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option you can simply truncate the table

From what I know you may not set the auto_increment lower than the highest value in your current table (protection against primary key conflicts)

Comment: I have tried setting it to a number bigger than the current max value, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

If there is some rows in your table you can not reset.

Because autoincrement numbers are unique.

@ok gives you a solution but in this case the rows will be deleted.

Takes a copy of your rows truncate table and load theme again

Answer (score 0):

You can only set AUTO_INCREMENT to a value that is bigger that the biggest id. 
So if you have any row, and dont want to delete it, you can lower the autoincrement value, but just to some value higher than your last inserted row.